# Как называется сервис онлайн редактора?

Tags: поиск-программ

Однажды мне попался необычный олнайн-редактор, типа блокнота. Его особенность заключалась в том, что в нем можно было писать текст в любом месте на странице, а используя колесико мышки, можно было изменить масштаб написанного текста. Вместе с тем, новый текст писался всегда шрифтом одного размера. В итоге получалось так, что можно было написать текст, потом его увеличить и рядом написать  уже текст помельче (сравнительно), потом обратно уменьшить до очень маленьких размеров и снова что-то написать, но в сравнении с уже написанным текстом, вводимые буквы были больше. Получалось что-то похожее на облако заметок с большими и маленькими записями. Но вот беда - я напрочь забыл как называется этот сервис. Поисковики выдают совсем не то, что я хочу. Возможно сервис уже не существует, но вдруг есть. Кто помнит и знает как его найти?

Comment: Можно самому такой сделать. По описанию вроде довольно просто.

Comment: предлагаю челлендж тут =)

Comment: OneNote - Microsoft

Comment: Да уже мысль в голове закрутилась. Думаю, что действительно быстрее сам напишу, чем смогу найти.